# how to auto select a grid record in extjs by using id?

Tags: extjs

I want to load a grid by highlighting a specific row by sending id attribute in extjs. I cannot choose the record for now. How can i do it? thanks....

I tried some codes which are commented in the code are. you can see below.

```
var GrideAktar = function (bilgim) {
    arr = bilgim.split(",");
    bilgi = arr[0];
    secilecek_id = arr[1];

    harita.hide();
    izgaralar.hide();
    chartlar.hide();
    izgara_yp_is_emirleri.hide();


    izgaralar.show();
    izgaralar.setHeight(merkez.getHeight());
    fileStore_yon.loadById(bilgi);
    tree.treeRefresh();

    cuIzgaraKay = null;
    cuAgacNode = bilgi;
    cuAgacSeciliNode = NodeParser(bilgi);
    cuAgacSeciliSehir = SehirParser(bilgi)
    fileGrid_yon.setHeight(merkez.getHeight());
    //fileGrid_yon.getSelectionModel().selectFirstRow();
    //fileGrid_yon.getSelectionModel().valueOf(id);
    //fileGrid_yon.getSelectionModel().selectRow(1);

    //   var idx = fileGrid_yon.getStore().indexOfId(secilek_id);
    //var rowEl = fileGrid_yon.getView().getRow(idx);
    //rowEl.scrollIntoView(fileGrid_yon.getGridEl(),false);
    Ext.select(secilecek_id);
    raporAlanListesiWindow.hide();
    //fileGrid_yon.getSelectionModel().selectRow( this.getStore().indexOfId(id) ); //raporSecenekleriForm.hide(); 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().select(store.getById(id));
```

Which will select the record in `store` by `id` in `grid`.

Comment: fileGrid_yon.getSelectionModel().select(fileStore_yon.getById(secilecek_id)); I try to insert it but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a race condition issue.  I'm guessing that your code creates a grid that loads from a remote source using ajax or something.  Try imbedding the row selection code in the 'load' event of the store:

```
var GrideAktar = function (bilgim) {
    arr = bilgim.split(",");
    bilgi = arr[0];
    secilecek_id = arr[1];

    harita.hide();
    izgaralar.hide();
    chartlar.hide();
    izgara_yp_is_emirleri.hide();


    izgaralar.show();
    izgaralar.setHeight(merkez.getHeight());
    fileStore_yon.on("load", function(){
        fileGrid_yon.getSelectionModel().select(fileStore_yon.getById(id));
    });
    fileStore_yon.loadById(bilgi);
    tree.treeRefresh();

    cuIzgaraKay = null;
    cuAgacNode = bilgi;
    cuAgacSeciliNode = NodeParser(bilgi);
    cuAgacSeciliSehir = SehirParser(bilgi)
    fileGrid_yon.setHeight(merkez.getHeight());
    //fileGrid_yon.getSelectionModel().selectFirstRow();
    //fileGrid_yon.getSelectionModel().valueOf(id);
    //fileGrid_yon.getSelectionModel().selectRow(1);

    //   var idx = fileGrid_yon.getStore().indexOfId(secilek_id);
    //var rowEl = fileGrid_yon.getView().getRow(idx);
    //rowEl.scrollIntoView(fileGrid_yon.getGridEl(),false);
    Ext.select(secilecek_id);
    raporAlanListesiWindow.hide();
    //fileGrid_yon.getSelectionModel().selectRow( this.getStore().indexOfId(id) ); //raporSecenekleriForm.hide(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks but it does not solve my problem, I want to focus the records which has id i sent

Comment: @CD..  Agreed +1.  Also user1702486, there is the option to accept the answer that helped you the most to solve your problem.

Comment: solution is not related with my question.

Comment: well...   the problem is that if you don't accept something as the answer this question will forever be in limbo with people opening it up to answer because it looks like you still need an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var index = gridPanel.store.find('fieldName', fieldValue);
gridPanel.getSelectionModel().select(gridPanel.store.getAt(index));
```